# How to use express-fileuploader-s3 ? (For Object Storage in Linode)

Tags: javascript, express, linode

I use framework Expressjs for upload file Object Storage using module express-fileupload-s3 . In here, I use code example :

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var mutilpart = require('connect-multiparty');
var uploader = require('express-fileuploader');
var S3Strategy = require('express-fileuploader-s3');

var app = express();
app.use('/upload/image', mutilpart());

uploader.use(new S3Strategy({
    uploadPath: '/',
    headers: {
        'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
    },
    options: {
        domain: 'myDomainBucketObjectStorage',
        key: 'accessKey',
        secret: 'secretKey',
        bucket: 'bucketname'
    }
}));

app.post('/upload/image', function (req, res, next) {
    uploader.upload('s3', req.files['images'], function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send(JSON.stringify(files));
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
```

Reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileuploader-s3

Output :

> [{"fieldName":"images","originalFilename":"example.png","path":"/tmp/example.png","headers":{"content-disposition":"form-data;
>   name=\"images\";
>   filename=\"example.png\"","content-type":"image/png"},"size":58261,"name":"example.png","type":"image/png","url":"https:[slash2]domain[dot]com//50cbadc0-151a-11ea-a82c-6fb771b09257.png"}]

Output I think is success, but after I check to Object Storage is empty file. Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this?